# Label truncates some symbols each line

Tags: ios, swift, label, uilabel

So I have a label:

```
let messageLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
messageLabel.text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20"
messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.chatScrollView.frame.size.width - 90, CGFloat.max)
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
messageLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
messageLabel.sizeToFit()
```

but when I look it I see:

[image]

if I try to put here twice more text it will look like:

[image]

why it is always cut some amount of symbols? 
How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout in your project?

Comment: because your frame of your scrollview is not height enough

Comment: @Kuba yes, but if I turn it off it would look like the same

Comment: try giving a custom frame with a big height and see what happens ?

Comment: I changed font size and it appeared to be well. Need to check it with big font size as well

Comment: Your label has this content always : messageLabel.text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20" ?

Comment: Have you tried using .ByCharWrapping instead of WordWrapping?

Comment: @Martijn I did. Result is almost the same